# What is the meaning of " flowing" and " curling"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> By a pomegranate juice stand, a man might be reading a newspaper and we
> can imagine what roiling political events might have provoked the
> **flowing, curling** words of the headline splashed across the front

the source is *The Good Enough Parent* (The School of Life, 2021)

Comment: I can't imagine why a sentence like that should appear in a self-help parenting guide, but it's a pretty weird text. English newspaper headlines ***don't*** flow or curl. Maybe your cited writer has been smoking something he shouldn't! I don't think he's what we might call a "careful" writer. Anglophones wouldn't normally encounter pomegranate juce stands, either, so perhaps it's just a really lazy translation from Arabic (whose newspaper headlines might well "flow and curl", for all I know).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the meaning of meaningless text

Comment: Published in 2021 by The School of Life
First published in the USA in 2022
70 Marchmont Street, London WC1N 1AB
Copyright © The School of Life 2021
Designed by Marcia Mihotich
Typeset by Kerrypress
Printed in Latvia by Livonia
All rights reserved. This book is sold subject to the condition that it shall not be
resold, lent, hired out or otherwise circulated without express prior consent of the
publisher.
A proportion of this book has appeared

Comment: Is that supposed to convince us it's a "credible, authoritative" text? I think the writer just confused himself by his metaphoric reference to ***roiling*** (tumultuous) political events, and forgot that the capital letters of typical English newspapers are actually more "sharp, angular", rather than flowing and curling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The headline in that context may have been written in a language with a flowing, curly script like [Cambodian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_script). Nothing in the quote suggests it's English. In fact, the pomegranate juice stand suggests this scene does not take place in an English-speaking country, and the fact that we have to "imagine" the political events on a newspaper that we can see suggests the headline is not in English. The question makes sense.

Comment: Excuse me ,I am a student .I want to translate it ,and give to my teacher soon.instead of helping me ,you critsized the context???? Is it important that the context is from English  or another language???

Comment: How does it make sense to ask what "flowing curling" newspaper headlines "mean" in English, when in fact English headlines ***don't*** flow and curl? This is just too bizarre! Besides, even though I can't see how the text meaningfully relates to Anglohone experience, the meanings of "flow" and "curl" can easily be established by reference to any English dictionary, for someone who wants to understand how those words might relate to, say, a Cambodian newspaper.

Comment: Any way! thanks